# What do the angle bracketed symbols at the end of a class name mean?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

For example look at this:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Could I use the <>s with a custom class? How do I use them?

Comment: ArrayList<CustomClass> s = new ArrayList<CustomClass>() ?

Comment: you can use like this `ArrayList s= new ArrayList();` and add object of any class you want

Comment: Do you understand my question? Like this: MyClass<String> class;

Comment: Declare your class as: `class MyClass<T> {}`

Answer (score 3):

You can put any class in the `<>` as long as it fulfills the generic class's constraints:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> arrayList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

You can define your own class to use the `<>` simply:

```
class MyGenericClass<E> {
    E e;
    MyGenericClass(E e) { this.e = e; }

    E getE() { return e; }
    void setE(E e) { this.e = e; }
}
```

Now you can make your own:

```
MyGenericClass<String> stuff = new MyGenericClass<String>("Foo");
System.out.println(stuff.getE());
```

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) gives you all the information needed. The section [Generic types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) shows how to declare and implement custom classes.

```
class MyClass<T> {
    ...
}
```